# Null decimal values occupying space in data page of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Here is the test table I have created.

```
USE [Test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_3]
(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [itemcode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [gain] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [loss] [decimal](18, 5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Against an id there can be three situations against an item for a date

1. Gain as finite, loss as 0.0
2. Gain as 0.0, loss as finite
3. Gain as null and loss as null (which means I don't know about the data)

As per my understanding, (3.) will still reserve space on the data page in SQL Server amounting to decimal data type and whether the column is null or not. Is the understanding correct for SQL Server 2012, 2014 and 2016?

If yes, is there a way (some data type, hints) that if `Gain` or `Loss` is null, no space is reserved in the database for them?

Comment: Disk space it pretty cheap now days

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, those columns will consume space wether they are null or have values.

If you expect a large proportion of those columns to be null and you require a way to reclaim that space, you can define the columns as SPARSE:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_3](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [itemcode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [gain] [decimal](18, 5) SPARSE NULL,
    [loss] [decimal](18, 5) SPARSE NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns

Comment: Thanks I will try the same after going through documentation. Also when exactly is the space reclaimed ?  Does it require some deliberate rebuilding of index or during the time the record is inserted,

Comment: At the time you create the table.  There are some caveats around using SPARSE columns, so, as with everything you do, make sure you read the documentation.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In your second question, DATALENGTH() is acting on the value returned in your query, not the column length:

```
insert Table_3 (id, itemcode, value, date, gain, loss)
values (1, 1, 1000.00000, '2018-02-28', NULL, NULL)

insert Table_3 (id, itemcode, value, date, gain, loss)
values (1, 1, 1000000000.00000, '2018-02-28', NULL, NULL)

select datalength(id),
datalength(itemcode),
datalength(value),
datalength(date)
from dbo.Table_3
```

You can see that the DATALENGTH for the first row is 5 but the second row is 9.

Comment: I read the documentation afterwards and therefore removed from the question. But cheers.